# A non well formed numeric value encountered in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have this code

```
private function calculateDefferedRevenue($price, $sub)
{
    $defferedrevenue = '0.00';

    if ($sub->has('fulfillment') && is_object($sub->fulfillment)) {
        $fulfillments = $sub->fulfillment;

        foreach ($fulfillments as $key => $fulfillment) {
            if ($fulfillment->has('shipments') && !is_null($fulfillment->shipments)) {
                $counts = self::countShipments($fulfillment->shipments);

                if (!empty($price) && $counts['shipmentCount'] > 0) {
                    $shippingFee        = self::getShippingFee($sub);
                    $shippingFees       = $counts['unshippedCount'] * $shippingFee;
                    $price              = self::deductUsingCoupon($price, $sub);
                    $eachShipmentAmount = $price / $counts['shipmentCount'];
                    $revenue            = $eachShipmentAmount * $counts['unshippedCount'];
                    $revenue            = $revenue + $shippingFees;
                    $defferedrevenue    = $defferedrevenue + $revenue;
                    $defferedrevenue    = number_format($defferedrevenue, 2);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $defferedrevenue;
}
```

and these are the set of values return from sentry after running lines aboove in the laravel queue jobs

```
{
counts: {
shipmentCount: 4, 
shippedCount: 1, 
unshippedCount: 3
}, 
defferedrevenue: 1,049.25, 
eachShipmentAmount: 349.75, 
key: 1, 
price: 1399.00, 
revenue: 1049.25, 
shippingFee: 0.00, 
shippingFees: 0, 
sub: Object Subscription
}
```

Why php is saying `A non well formed numeric value encountered` on this line

```
$defferedrevenue    = $defferedrevenue + $revenue;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `number_format()` here, which might add commas:

```
$defferedrevenue    = $defferedrevenue + $revenue;
$defferedrevenue    = number_format($defferedrevenue, 2);
```

So on the next loop iteration, you're likely getting something like:

```
$defferedrevenue = "1,234" + 1;
```

This generates a notice because "1,234" is a string that can't be automatically interpreted as a number. Just get rid of the `number_format()` line from inside the loop and put it after the loop ends:

```
return number_format($defferedrevenue, 2);
```